# convert string to byte with 120 and higher value of string

Tags: java

How do I convert String to byte with string having value more then 120. It may range till 255.

So is there some method which let me do it? And also when I am doing it after changing it int int. It is not full filling my requirement. Can any body help?

Comment: One method to convert a String to a byte is `return (byte)s.length();`.  You **really** need to specify what sort of conversion you're looking for - state your requirements (which aren't being fulfilled), else how are we supposed to help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Byte.parseByte() ?